# How to define right pin on ATmega8

Tags: atmega, arduino-ide

I wrote simple code in arduino IDE like this :

```
void setup() {
pinMode(PC4,OUTPUT);
pinMode(PC5,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
if(analogRead(PC5)<15)
digitalWrite(PC4,LOW);
else
digitalWrite(PC4,HIGH);
}
```

and my problem is the arduino IDE defined PC4 as PD4, PC5 defined as PC5.

Comment: So you probably have chosen a wrong board in your project settings. Or it has a bug.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I selected ATmega8

Comment: Arduino is not C!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `A4` and `A5` to specify pins `PC4` and `PC5` respectively

Like `pinMode(A4, OUTPUT)`[image]

Comment: It is working, thanks, but how do i know `PC4` is `A4` on ATmega8? Is anywhere list with pin names or something like that? I know that on ATmega328p it is called `A4` because on arduino uno it is writed on board. I know as well that ATmega8 and ATmega328p have the same pinout, but anyway...

Comment: As you mentioned, atmega328 and atmega8 have the same pinout , this means that every pin on 328 maps out to the atmega8 in the same way.